# Reverting screwed up versioning of open-source library

Tags: github, repository, versioning, jitpack

I've been writing [a library to get radial ui widgets in libgdx](https://github.com/payne911/PieMenu/releases).

Being my first-ever library to be written, I had to get my hands dirty with JitPack and did a few experiments to try to do things right. However, being overly enthusiastic about my library being used (rookie mistake), I released a first version kind of early.

At that point, I wanted to follow the `semantic versioning` principles and so for every change that broke the API, I increased the main number. At the current rhythm, in just a few days, the library might reach `v3.0.0`, which is laughable in some way.

What is the best way for me to start back from 0, but while keeping the same library's name?

I know JitPack's FAQ says:

> **What happens if a tag or repository is deleted on GitHub?**
>
> If the project was already built then JitPack will continue serving
>   the existing artifacts. It will not rebuild the project at the new
>   tag. In case you need to redo a release the best option is to create a
>   new version on GitHub.

But I'm left unsatisfied with that answer: it mentions "the best option", thus hinting at the fact that there might be other solutions. Also, when they mention `create a new version on GitHub`, do they mean "`advance the current version in a new release, once again`", or "`create an entirely new repo`" ?

I'm decently confident I just screwed up, generally speaking, so that I'll have to live with it or create a new repo, but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way for me to start back from 0, but while keeping the same library's name?

Technically you can but you shouldn't : artificats still served by jitpack, at some point you may have version duplicates which would be a mess for existing users of your library.

> when they mention create a new version on GitHub, do they mean "advance the current version in a new release, once again", or "create an entirely new repo" ?

I think they suggest to delete your release/tag on github, recreate them based on other commits in order to rebuild release versions. But you shouldn't do that neither, again, it'll mess with artifcats already downloaded by users of your library.

Conclusion, you can't really get back when a release/tag has been published. And as you said: live with it or create a new repo with a new group and/or artifact name.